# Is it possible to make click circle smaller for checkbox / radiobutton?

Tags: angular, checkbox, styles, angular-material2

I was wondering, in Angular Material2, is it possible to make the selection circle smaller?

When I tried to box it, the circle was cut into rectangle or square. Example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```html
<div class="body">
      <h4><strong>Custom Radiobutton</strong></h4>
      <div class="radiobuttons">
         <div class="rdio rdio-primary radio-inline"> 
           <input name="radio" value="1" id="radio1" type="radio" checked>
           <label for="radio1">All</label>
         </div>
         <div class="rdio rdio-primary radio-inline">
           <input name="radio" value="2" id="radio2" type="radio">
           <label for="radio2">Select</label>
         </div>
     </div>
     <h4><strong>Custom Checkbox</strong></h4>
     <div class="cust-checkbox">
       <div class="custom-checkbox">
         <input name="noti_6" class="checkbox-custom" id="noti_6" value="6" type="checkbox">
         <label class="checkbox-custom-label" for="noti_6">Check me</label>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.rdio {
    position: relative;
}
.rdio input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
}
.rdio label {
    padding-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 7px !important;
}
.rdio label:before {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #fbc52d;
    background: #fff;
}
.rdio input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 0px;
}
.rdio input[type="radio"]:disabled + label {
    color: #999;
}
.rdio input[type="radio"]:disabled + label:before {
    background-color: #fbc52d;
}
.rdio input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fbc52d;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.rdio-default input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    border-color: #fbc52d;
}
.rdio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    border-color: #fbc52d;
}
.rdio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    background-color: #fbc52d;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"],
.custom-checkbox label {
    /*margin-bottom:0px !important;*/
    
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #fbc52d;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    font: normal normal normal 12px/1 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: '\e013';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -7px;
    left: 2px;
    color: #fbc52d;
    xtransition: all .2s;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"][data-indeterminate] + label:after {
    content: '\2212';
    left: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #dadada;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #fbc52d;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
    color: #fbc52d;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
.custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
    border: 1px solid #fbc52d;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
.custom-checkbox label:hover:before {
    border: 1px solid #fbc52d !important;
}
.custom-checkbox [type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:hover:before,
.custom-checkbox [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:hover:before {
    border: 1px solid #fbc52d !important;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply. This is not exactly what I had in mind. I don't want to make the checkbox bigger. I just want to make the effect of the cicle draw fired onClick to be smaller.